# Set the maximum speed of robot

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know how can I set the maximum speed of the robot manipulator. I am currently using `set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor(1)`, is there any function that can help to increase it's speed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408819/set-the-maximum-speed-of-robot/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your ros_package their should be a joint_limits.yaml file, in which the speed limits are set.
There you can set the speed limit, or turn of speed limit by setting has_velocity_limits to false. The yaml file should look similar to the following:

```
joint_limits:
    joint_1:
    min_position: -2.84
    max_position: 2.84
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.141592653589793
    has_acceleration_limits: false
    max_acceleration: 0
```

---

Originally posted by [nils_iseke](https://answers.ros.org/users/120024/nils_iseke/) with karma: 76 on 2022-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0